# How much carrot juice should I drink to get orange?

Tags: diet, juice

I want to be orange. Have an orange skin to look tanned without exposing myself to the sun. I read that it is possible to get orange color of skin by drinking lots of carrot juice.

How much carrot juice should I drink to be orange? And how often?

Comment: Pretty sure this should be moved to Skeptics.se, but for what it's worth: [This article](http://juicerecipes.com/blog/does-carrot-juice-make-you-turn-orange/) claims that the different skin color is a temporary effect and won't last no matter how much juice you drink.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you should consider using a tanning stain product that bodybuilders use.  It typically lasts 3 weeks and wears off.  It will not wash off.  It's usually applied with a small foam brush.  The advantage to this approach is that you don't have to consume anything to get the look you want, and, you don't need to sit in the sun.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's an article](http://www.shz.de/nachrichten/ratgeber/ernaehrung-gesundheit/und-ploetzlich-war-ich-orange-id278490.html) about a man who had this happen, but it's in German.

According to the article, he drank 2 bottles of carrot juice per day over a period of three months. However, it only affected his hands and feet, not the whole body.

Besides, the color is really *orange*, not brown. At best it will look like a really bad fake tan. If you're contant with that, why not use actual fake tan products? Much quicker and more reliable...